# Android FreeRDP SIGSEGV crash on samsung device

Tags: android, sigabrt, segmentation-fault, native-code, freerdp

We have integrated FreeRDP in android application. Some of the devices like Samsung, We are getting SIGSEGV & SIGABRT crashes randomly. These are not reproducible issues and logs are not showing any specific method that causing the issue.

I am posting some logs here. Could you please let me know if anyone has any idea about this? 
    Crash reason:  SIGSEGV
    Crash address: 0x0
    Process uptime: not available

```
Thread 195 (crashed)
 0  libfreerdp2.so + 0x20ef0
     r0 = 0x00000000    r1 = 0x00000000    r2 = 0x00000000    r3 = 0x00000000
     r4 = 0x8401c380    r5 = 0xb0800f6d    r6 = 0xbb7fc920    r7 = 0x00000078
     r8 = 0x09f7b70c    r9 = 0x09f7b6e0   r10 = 0x8ed55cc8   r12 = 0xb0842600
     fp = 0xbb7fc7ec    sp = 0xbb7fc7d8    lr = 0x8ebde450    pc = 0x8ebd8ef0
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  libc.so + 0x47f6b
     sp = 0xbb7fc7e4    pc = 0xb0800f6d
    Found by: stack scanning
```